# capturing crash in mainwindow when Qt plugin crashed

Tags: c++, qt, qtplugin

iam having three plugins loaded (Qt Plugins using qpluginLoader) to my application. the plugins are different modules , in many cases plugins crashed as development is still in progress.

so when any one of the plugin crashed , i have to automatically store the last window state of my mainwindow.

i tried QApplication::notify(QObject *receiver, QEvent *event)  function,but still im not able to capture the crash.

Comment: What is your question and which plugins are you talking about?

Comment: It is not the best idea to do anything after AV. May be you could save the state before any plugin call?

Comment: @sithreal im using Qt plugins . using pluginLoader say i loaded plotter plugin which is having qwt plot datas. so if the plotterPlugin crashed at any scenario , i have to capture the current mainWindow (where plotterPlugin) loaded state.

Comment: @KonstantinL : crash happens on certain operation in plugin after loading, so i cant predict the exact time.

Comment: Well, I warned you :) Use (/EHa) and try { .. } catch( ... ) { .. }.

Comment: BTW, it would be useful to add an example of crash call stack to your question.